# How to go to prev/nextFrame only when all targets are dragged?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

My question is how to go to go to previous/next frame after 'monkey' and 'dog' are both dragged out of the scrollpane.

The file is placed below:
https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D9726155_61875891_24948

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: Why don't you check using user-defined Boolean vars like onStage=true or insideScrollPane=false if both movieclips are dragged on the stage.?

Answer (score 0):

2 ways I can think of
1- check x and y position of monkey if they are lower or higher than the x and y of scrollpane then go to next frame
2- set and invisible collision area and check if they collide.

I would help more with the code but i didn't find the objects to drag ^_^